# IPhone SDK - How do I implement an Apple like rating UIAlertView?

Tags: iphone, uialertview

Does anyone have an Idea how to implement an UIAlertView for rating purpose like Apple show when you are removing an app from the iPhone?
You can choose how many stars to rate the app or don't rate it at all.
I already have a view that shows the stars according to the user touches but don't know how to connect it to the UIAlertView...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A good tutorial how to do this:
http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2010/05/custom-alert-views.html

Comment: You should have posted this as a comment. In it's current form, it does not provide the specific information that @Inetanel wanted for his purposes. Welcome to StackOverflow :)

Comment: It provides every information it should. I don't want to copy paste the whole tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

I like the [TSAlertView](https://github.com/TomSwift/TSAlertView). It's a complete replacement of UIAlertView based on UIView. So you don't use any private APIs. 
I used it in multiple projects and I really like it. Take a look at it. With that one it should be easy to add your "starview" to the AlertView becuase you have methods to add a contentView.